# solr datetime sorting is not working

Tags: solr

I am trying to sort the data by the `"created"` field.

This is my data `"created":"2016-05-24T09:45:40Z"`

This is the managed schema configuration:

```
<fieldType name="dates" class="solr.TrieDateField" positionIncrementGap="0" docValues="true" multiValued="true" precisionStep="0"/>

<field name="created" type="tdates"/>
```

while sorting am getting error

Message: Solr HTTP error: OK (500)

```
{
  "error": {
    "msg": "unexpected docvalues type SORTED_SET for field 'created'
    (expected=NUMERIC). Use UninvertingReader or index with docvalues.", 
    "trace": "java.lang.IllegalStateException: unexpected docvalues type 
      SORTED_SET for field 'created' (expected=NUMERIC). 
      Use UninvertingReader or index with docvalues.
        at org.apache.lucene.index.DocValues.checkField(DocValues.java:212)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.DocValues.getNumeric(DocValues.java:227)
      ...
```

How to fix this error ?

Comment: Which version of Solr? Are there differing versions in your cluster? Have the index been created by a different version of Solr than the one reading it? Have the field been made multiValued _after_ indexing happened?

Comment: solr 6  . created indexed like this "created":"2016-05-24T10:56:13Z",

Answer (score -1):

I guess you're having this error because you changed the schema configuration without reload all the documents into the collection.